# Can I limit the mouse prompt position in InputField?

Tags: string-manipulation, inputfield, mouseclick

I wrote the Manipulate code in double quotation marks in InputField.

```
Manipulate[str, Style[Control@{str, "   "}, 20]]
```

Above, I can create a prompt status by clicking on any location within InputField with my mouse. However, I would like to make the mouse prompt status only within double quotes and set it to be able to enter.

[image]

Is it possible to make these settings code?

Comment: This sounds like a very weird UX hack. Why do you actually want this? Why not use `ToString`?

Comment: I want to enter a Mathematica command statement in the form of StandardForm. My code must be written in double quotes to create the state I want. However, if you write outside of the double quotation marks, the entered command turns into a raw code.